# What is pictured in the back of Falcon 9's 2015 launch photo?

Tags: spacex, launch, falcon-9

Wikipedia (actually Wikimedia) has [an image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5c/Launch_of_Falcon_9_carrying_ABS-EUTELSAT_%2816510243060%29.jpg) of Falcon 9's 2015 launch during its night flight (16th flight in total) that took place on Sunday, March 1, 2015 at 10:50pm ET:

[image]

I was wondering what is pictured in the background near the right bottom corner?

There's a lot of light pictured in that place. Is this a "normal operational" of the flight's control area (i.e. happens during any flight) or does that much of light suggest some other rocket's engines burning / another rocket's preparation for the next flight?

Comment: That's just the glow of normal street and work lighting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's one of the other launch complexes at CCAFS, probably Complex 37. The vehicle in your picture is launching from Complex 40.  The water in the foreground makes it likely that this picture was taken from the NASA causeway or from Jetty Park (just off the bottom of this map).

[image]

Here's a little better picture from the same angle. You can see that it's a launch complex better in this one.

[image]